# How to convert a bit string to base64 in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, base64, bit-manipulation

I have a bit string that I want to convert to base64 but it doesn't look like there's a native function to do this and I couldn't find a node module either. ):

Input: `100110110101000110100011011001100010110100011011001100100110100011000001100000110000011000001100001001010100111110000011001111100101010011111010011100010110001001001001100000110100111010010100111110000111001000100000110001001000101100111110011001001001101011010001011001001101001010000011000100100100110000011010011`

Output: base64 representation of that equivalent binary value

Maybe a better question is how to convert a bit string into a buffer? Not sure

Comment: Bit strings are not something that nodejs has any native support for.  You're going to have to either parse/convert it yourself or find a library to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the main thing is converting the string into something easier to convert to base64 and then converting that to base64.

In the code below, we do these conversion sequences:

- bit string -> BigInt -> array of byte-sized ints -> binary string -> base64
- base64 -> binary string -> array of byte-sized bit strings -> bit string

```js
const encode = bitstr => {
  const bytes = [];
  // convert bit string to BigInt
  let value = BigInt('0b' + bitstr);
  // chop it up into bytes
  while (value > 0n) {
    bytes.unshift(Number(value & 0xffn));
    value >>= 8n;
  }
  // convert to binary string and encode as base64
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes));
};

const decode = b64 => {
  // decode base64 to binary string
  const bstr = atob(b64);
  // convert binary string to bit string
  return new Array(bstr.length).fill(0).map(
    (_,i) => bstr.charCodeAt(i).toString(2).padStart(8, i ? '0' : '')
  ).join('');
};

const bitstr = '100110110101000110100011011001100010110100011011001100100110100011000001100000110000011000001100001001010100111110000011001111100101010011111010011100010110001001001001100000110100111010010100111110000111001000100000110001001000101100111110011001001001101011010001011001001101001010000011000100100100110000011010011';
const encoded = encode(bitstr);
const decoded = decode(encoded);

console.log(bitstr);
console.log(encoded);
console.log(decoded);
```